# drop the first n characters in column psypark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, substring, slice

I am trying to drop the first two characters in a column for every row in my pyspark data frame. The length of the following characters is different, so I can't use the solution with [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916482/python-spark-extract-characters-from-dataframe).

example data frame:

```
columns = ['text']
vals = [(h0123),(b012345), (xx567)]
```

**EDIT**
actually the problem becomes more complicated as sometimes I have a letter and two zeros as first characters and then need to drop both 0.

Example:

```
columns = ['text']
vals = [(h0123),(b012345), (x00567), (L0034)]
```

Expected outcome:

```
(123),(12345), (567), (34)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to call [`substring`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring) and pass in the length of the string minus `n` as the `len` argument.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

n = 2
df.withColumn(
    "new_text",
    expr("substring(text, {n}+1, length(text)-{n})".format(n=n))
).show()
#+-------+--------+
#|   text|new_text|
#+-------+--------+
#|  h0123|     123|
#|b012345|   12345|
#|  xx567|     567|
#+-------+--------+
```

You an also turn this into a function:

```python
def lstrip(column, n):
    # should probably add error checking on inputs
    return expr("substring(`{col}`, {n}+1, length(`{col}`)-{n})".format(col=column, n=n))

df.withColumn("new_text", lstrip(column="text", n=n)).show()
# Same as above
```

Comment: this works fine thank you! I realised I have another dimension to my problem. could you maybe have a look?